# Load a views block in a tpl file with his custom template

Tags: views, theming

I have a custom tpl file for a node type, in this file i want to load a views block i created.
This block has a custom template file to style the block itself.

I load the views block in the node template file with views_embed_view() but this just gives me the default html of the block and not the output of the blocks tpl file.

Is this possible with the views_embed_view() function or do i need to use some other function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to do this you just need to use the views_embed_view() function. I just had a typo in my template file.

So for someone who's looking for a way to do something similar:

```
<?php print views_embed_view('VIEW_NAME', 'DISPLAY_NAME', 'ARGUMENTS'); ?>
```